# How not to clear the html form when sending data

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form in Html and after sending the data, I have a task to leave the information entered by the user, and not to clean the form.
Form exemple:

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="search" id="search" name="req" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" role="combobox"
           placeholder="write here" aria-live="polite"><br>
<div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-1" type="radio" name="radio" value="first" checked>
    <label for="radio-1">first</label>
</div>
<div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-2" type="radio" name="radio" value="Second">
    <label for="radio-2">second</label>
</div>
</form>
```

Please suggest

Comment: And form must be submitted via `POST` method to receive information in back-end

Comment: Thanks but prefer use this method here and this solution is not quite suitable because I would like to refrain from using PHP since the project does not use it

Comment: Front end does not care what back-end is, so sending data via Ajax has nothing to do with PHP

Comment: OK I understend that here I will use PHP as it's better solution then js

Answer (score 1):

Call `event.preventDefault()` and make an http request using js

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="search" id="search" name="req" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" role="combobox"
           placeholder="write here" aria-live="polite" value="<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['req'])){ echo $_REQUEST['req'];}?>"><br>
<div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-1" type="radio" name="radio" value="first" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['radio']) && $_REQUEST['radio']=='first'){ echo 'checked';}?>>
    <label for="radio-1">first</label>
</div>
<div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-2" type="radio" name="radio" value="Second"  <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['radio']) && $_REQUEST['radio']=='Second'){ echo 'checked';}?>>
    <label for="radio-2">second</label>
</div>
</form>
```

Or use Ajax